# how can I prove that $arccot(z)=\frac{1}{2i}ln(\frac{z+i}{z-i})$ also need to indicate any posible restriction

Tags: complex-numbers

Well I am really confused about this problem, and can't find any related example,  I would appreciate if you can give me some hints on how to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$z=\cot{y} \implies z=\frac{i(e^{iy}+e^{-iy})}{e^{iy}-e^{-iy}}\implies ze^{2iy}-ie^{2iy}=z+i\implies e^{2iy}=\frac{z+i}{z-i}\implies$
$$\cot^{-1}{z}=\frac{1}{2i}\text{log}\frac{z+i}{z-i}$$

Solve for $y$.

Comment: thanks, I solved it